# What is a global transaction?

Tags: java, jta

JSR 907 `JTA 1.2` defines the "global transaction" term:

> The UserTransaction.begin method starts a *global transaction* and
>   associates the transaction with the calling thread.

What does that mean? Is it the outermost transaction or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the difference between a local transaction and a global transaction is resource bound.
A global transaction will span multiple resources. A local transaction is limited to one resource/datasource.

E.g.

In a global transaction you will write to the DB and send a message over a queue.

This is nicely explained here:
http://integrationspot.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/jta-transactions-local-and-global.html

> **Global Transactions (XA)**
>
> When a managed data source is configured for global transactions, it
> returns connections that can participate in global transactions. A
> global transaction (also called a distributed transaction) enlists
> more than one resource in the transaction.
>
> Global Transactions provide the ability to work with multiple
> transactional resources (typically relational databases and message
> queues).

Comment: Integeresting, thanks. I just want to clarify whether JTA is an implemetnation of Open/XA?

Comment: Open/XA is an architecture that defines how global & local transactions will interact. JTA is modeled on this architecture.