# Does global tranactions same as XA transactions?

Tags: spring, transactions, xa

from Spring documentation(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html):

> 16.2.1 Global transactions
>
> Global transactions enable you to work with multiple transactional
>   resources, typically relational databases and message queues. The
>   application server manages global transactions through the JTA, which
>   is a cumbersome API to use (partly due to its exception model).
>   Furthermore, a JTA UserTransaction normally needs to be sourced from
>   JNDI, meaning that you also need to use JNDI in order to use JTA.
>   Obviously the use of global transactions would limit any potential
>   reuse of application code, as JTA is normally only available in an
>   application server environment.
>
> Previously, the preferred way to use global transactions was via EJB
>   CMT (Container Managed Transaction): CMT is a form of declarative
>   transaction management (as distinguished from programmatic transaction
>   management). EJB CMT removes the need for transaction-related JNDI
>   lookups, although of course the use of EJB itself necessitates the use
>   of JNDI. It removes most but not all of the need to write Java code to
>   control transactions. The significant downside is that CMT is tied to
>   JTA and an application server environment. Also, it is only available
>   if one chooses to implement business logic in EJBs, or at least behind
>   a transactional EJB facade. The negatives of EJB in general are so
>   great that this is not an attractive proposition, especially in the
>   face of compelling alternatives for declarative transaction
>   management.

For me it looks like distributed transaction description(XA).

Am I wrong or Spring really calls XA tranactions as global.

Comment: AFAIK, "global transaction" is the appropriate term. XA is a standard interface/protocol to enable global transactions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165900/what-is-a-global-transaction